# setTimeout(function() not working properly on SP Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, popup

I need to open a pop up window that closes automatically after x seconds.
This code works fine outside Sharepoint:

```
 function openWin1() {
var myWindow1 = window.open("http://url here", "myWindow1", "width=500,height=400");

setTimeout(function(){myWindow1.close()}, 6000);
} 

<button onclick="openWin1()"> Open "myWindow1"</button>
```

But when I add it to a SP Online publishing page, the "parent" page refreshes in the background - the pop up doesn't close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint pages are forms and the default button is running your JavaScript and then submitting the form. Set the button type to "button" to override this default behavior.

```
<button type="button" onclick="openWin1()"> Open "myWindow1"</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on mike, yes you need "`type`" also in the JS code just use `#` to refer to the current site

```
<script>
       function openWin1() {
          var myWindow1 = window.open("#", "myWindow1", "width=500,height=400");

          setTimeout(function(){myWindow1.close()}, 6000);
       } 
</script>

<input type="button" value="click here to open page" onclick="openWin1()"/>

<button type="button" onclick="openWin1()"> click here to open page</button>
```

both button types work fine.

Comment: thanks, but the site being opened in the pop up isn't the current site.

Comment: just change the '#' , the code above opens up the same site and page that you put the code in. If you want a specific site than just update the '#'